# Primary key is not generated

Tags: spring, postgresql

I can not understand what it is connected with, I have no longer generated id, maybe it is connected with the update version of the spring. What do I get when I try to access JPA functions

```
Hibernate:insert into "user" (date_created, date_updated, activation_code, active, email, first_name, last_name, last_password_reset, password, purshased_products, roles, temporary_password, user_avatar, username, validaty_time) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select currval('"user"_id_seq')
```

these are my logs
how my id is generated

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<T> {
  @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected T id;
}
```

my model

```
 public class User extends BaseEntity<Integer> {


public enum Roles {
    ADMIN
}

private String firstName;}
```

I think we should also check the migration, but I don’t understand what’s wrong with them

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
id                  SERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,


username            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
password            VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
email               VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
first_name          VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
last_name           VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
last_password_reset TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
roles               JSONB        NOT NULL,
active              BOOLEAN      NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
date_created        TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
date_updated        TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()

);
```

the problem starts at the moment when the repository goes through the database.
But why throws such an error I can’t understand in any way, maybe something should change in migrations?

[image]

Comment: So what is the error?

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid name syntax

Comment: i add screen my error

Comment: Maybe you should avoid reserved word __user__? This seems bad: `select currval('"user"_id_seq')`

Comment: Do you recommend renaming a table user?